# Python bar plot with two arrays

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

I have two numpy arrays `X` and `GX` (float and int respectively) and I want to bin the `X` array (and thus corresponding `GX` values which saves the frequency) and plot a histogram with bins on x-axis and frequency on the y-axis. I have tried using pandas' `qcut`, `cut` and matplotlib's `histogram` as well. None of them seems to work. I have created bins and frequencies with numpy from scratch but all I can get is a scatter plot.

```
bins   = np.linspace(min(X), max(X),100)
freq   = []
countl = 0
for i in range(len(bins)-1):
    count = 0
    for j in range(len(X)):
        if bins[i]<X[j]<bins[i+1]:
            count += np.sum(GX[np.where(X==X[j])])
    freq.append(count)
for j in X:
    if bins[-2]<j<bins[-1]:
        countl += np.sum(GX[np.where(X==j)])

freq.append(countl)
plt.figure(figsize=(7,7))
plt.scatter(bins,freq,c='b')
```

Instead of the scatterplot, how can I get the bar graph or histogram (and probably a better method to bin values)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your given code, as you already calculated each of the bins, a histogram is just a bar plot of those bins:

```py
plt.bar(bins, freq, width=bins[1]-bins[0], color='crimson', ec='black')
```

Note that the test `bins[i] < X[j] < bins[i+1]` would leave out the X-values that are exactly equal to a bin bound. In most situations such equality is very unlikely, except for the minimum and the maximum of X. Therefore, `bins[i] <= X[j] < bins[i+1]` would be safer. Also, to fit the very last value, you could extend the bins with just an epsilon: e.g. `bins = np.linspace(min(X), max(X)+0.000001, 100)` (depending on the magnitude of X making sure epsilon is very small, but not neglected in the `smaller than` test).

Alternatively, and provided the sum of GX isn't too large to cause memory problems, you could just use [`np.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) to repeat the `X` array using `GX` as repetition factors. Then, matplotlib can just calculate the histogram in the usual way:

```py
all_X = np.repeat(X, GX)
plt.hist(all_X, bins=100, color='crimson', ec='black')
```